# how to make div center horizontally with fixed position?

Tags: css, html, center

I want div to be center horizontally, css code is this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    width:500px;
            margin: auto;/*left:auto; right:auto;*/
}
</style>
```

and html code:

```
<body>
<div id="footer">hello world</div>
</body>
```

I think there is no need to explain my css code, it is almost self-explanatory, but the div is not center horizontally, is there any way to make this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: position:fixed and margin: auto; don't work well together, I am working on a solution for you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

```
#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -40%;
    left:50%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q47W/)

The point to be noted here is, the negative `margin-left` of exactly half value of `width` and set the `left` 50 % of the body

Comment: your answer and @gregbenner's are both use this 'trick', first of all, thank you. I also just searched google and others also use this way, I am wondering if there is a no `trick` way to do it?

Comment: This is actually a nice solution. But it is not exactly what he wants to do. This way the footer will become responsive and won't have it's fixed width of 500px.

Comment: ya @Nick, but I have also mentioned that the trick behind it. (s)he can easily change the dimensions as (s)he likes.

Comment: @Sachin yep, you are right. There is probably no other way than using a trick like this or a container DIV.

Comment: So @HiwayChe accept the answer you have used. Because there are probably no better answers to give.

Comment: @Nick, ok, I prefer container using DIV to using trick, but if I use the former, I have to change too many html code(adding container div), that's too horrible, I will pay attention to this question next time. After all thank everybody.

Comment: instead of setting `margin-left`, we can also set `transform: translateX(-50%);`  This way we don't need to calculate half the value every time

Answer (score 8):

This should work well for you. It works by adding a container div.

```
<style>

#footer-container{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer
{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:red;
}
</style>


<div id="footer-container">
      <div id="footer">hello world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the "text-align:center;" will cause the text to center and IE6 to work. if you don't want to center, but like IE6 to work. add text-align:left to the #footer div.

Answer (score 6):

Put another div inside it with relative position, margin: auto.
Give the fixed one 100% width.

Otherwise you can hack it with negative margin 'trick'

```
div { 
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with modern browsers you can use the flexbox layout module: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.

Flexbox documentation: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes
*Note: Can't post more than two links due to my rep.*

---

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa6ttkg1/4/).

(Using a `footer` tag instead of a `div#footer` as it's simpler.)

```
<div id="footer-container">
  <footer>hello world</footer>
<div>
```

```
#footer-container {
  bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  width: 500px;

  background-color: red;
}
```

`justify-content: center;` 'centers' `#footer-container`'s children, which is just the `footer` element in this case.

This is very similar to Nick N.'s solution, except that you don't have to reset the `text-align` property on the footer, and that this is probably the non-'trick' way that you wanted.

The accepted solution is slightly off because the footer's width in that case is variable (80%) instead of at 500px.

---

To other readers, if your parent is a `form` element, and the child is an `input` element, use `flex: 1;` on the `input` (child) element, and use `max-width: 500px;` instead of `width: 500px;`. Using `flex: 1;` should make the `input` element expand to fill the `form` element's width, which it might not otherwise do.

Comment: This solution works great.  Should really have a way of tagging answers as 'modern browsers' so we can sort them to the top when only supporting modern browsers.

Comment: this is great , thank you